# Pass props to global context provider from function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I looking for help understanding how to pass `props` to a context provider from within a `function` of a `child` component.

I have a global provider which I want to hold `data` from a form, more specifically the `error` data if the `onSubmit` fails.

Using `createContext` I have a global provider

```
import React, { createContext } from 'react';

interface InterfaceProps {
  children?: any;
}

interface InterfaceState {
  error: any;
  toggleAuthError: any;
}

const GlobalContext = createContext({
  error: null,
  toggleAuthError: () => {}
});

export class GlobalProvider extends React.Component<InterfaceProps, InterfaceState> {
  public toggleAuthError = ({ authError }: any) => {
    this.setState({ error: authError });
  };

  public state = {
    error: null,
    toggleAuthError: this.toggleAuthError
  };

  public render() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    return <GlobalContext.Provider value={this.state as any}>{children}</GlobalContext.Provider>;
  }
}

export const GlobalConsumer = GlobalContext.Consumer;
```

Then within my form `child` component I have a function called `onSubmit`.

```
public handleFormSubmit = async (data: { email: string; password: string }) => {
    const { form } = this.props;
    const { email, password } = data;

    await form
      ...
      .catch((error: any) => {
        toggleAuthError(error); // Want this to trigger the function and pass error to the context provider
        this.setState({
          loading: false
        });
      });
  };
```

How can I pass `error` to `this.toggleAuthError` in the context provider?

Comment: I posted an alternate solution showing how you can access the `toggleAuthError` method in callback function.

Comment: I updated my solution to show how to pass the new value to the `toggleAuthError` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap your child component with the GlobalConsumer in order to access the context value. Something like this:

```
<MyContext.Consumer>
  {({toggleAuthError}) => /* render something based on the context value */}
</MyContext.Consumer>
```

Then you can simply pass the `toggleAuthError` to the handleFormSubmit function.

Comment: Thank you very much. However I am getting an error of `Property 'toggleAuthError' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & InterfaceProps'.ts(2322)` using this method. Any ideas why?

Comment: That's a typescript error. You need to define a type for toggleAuthError variable or just put any after the variable if you don't want to handle types for this.({toggleAuthError}:any) => ...

Comment: Thanks. I've done that but still no good. I'll put another question out there and then I'll accept your question. Because of our component library I had avoided this way but by bringing into a parent and passing down `toggleAuthError` it'll work. Was just hoping for a solution that could have been achieved in the function itself. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Ovidiu, using `Context.Consumer` is great if your component is a function component.

But if your component extends React.Component you can use [`Context.contextType`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#classcontexttype). This lets you consume the nearest current value of that Context type using `this.context`.

Using this setup, you can access the `toggleAuthError` method within a callback function.

In your case, in your `child` component (if it's a Class) you would use:

```
static contextType = GlobalContext;
```

and then can access the `toggleAuthError` method using `this.context.toggleAuthError`.

The example below shows both methods - `Context.contextType` and `Context.Consumer` to use both parts of your context (`error`, and `toggleAuthError`).

```js
const GlobalContext = React.createContext({
  error: 0,
  toggleAuthError: () => {}
});

class GlobalProvider extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.toggleAuthError = (newError) => {
      this.setState(state => ({
        error: newError
      }))
    };
    
    this.state = {
      error: 0,
      toggleAuthError: this.toggleAuthError,
    };
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <GlobalContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        {this.props.children}
      </GlobalContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}

const Form = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ToggleAuthErrorButton />
      <Error />
    </div>
  )
}

// A React component which uses context using Context.contextType
class ToggleAuthErrorButton extends React.Component {
  static contextType = GlobalContext;
  
  toggleError = () => {
    return this.context.toggleAuthError(this.context.error + 1);
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.toggleError}>Toggle Auth Error</button>
    )
  }
}

// A function component which uses context using Context.Consumer
const Error = () => {
  return (
    <GlobalContext.Consumer>
      {({error}) => {
        return (
          <div>Error {error}</div>
        )
      }}
    </GlobalContext.Consumer>
  )
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <GlobalProvider>
        <Form />
      </GlobalProvider>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: You would need the `toggleAuthError` function to update `state.error` with the error passed to `toggleAuthError`. I have updated the solution to show how this could be done.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. As soon as I wrote that comment I realised my mistake and corrected.